# Trouble Booting Custom Kernel with QEMU: dracut-initqueue timeout waiting for /dev/sysvg/root

Tags: linux-kernel, fedora, qemu, initrd, initramfs

I am trying to boot a custom Linux kernel using QEMU and encountering an issue where the boot process hangs with a `dracut-initqueue` timeout. I compiled the kernel using a `.config` file from a Fedora VM and also copied the `initrd.img` from the same VM.

##### QEMU Command:

Here's the QEMU command I am using to boot the VM:

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -nographic -vga none -smp 1 -m 2G -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -initrd initrd.img -append "root=/dev/sysvg/root console=ttyS0" -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=rootdisk -drive file=Fedora-Server-KVM-38-1.6.x86_64.qcow2,if=none,cache=none,id=rootdisk,format=qcow2 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=extradisk -drive file=fedoradisk.qcow2,if=none,cache=none,id=extradisk,format=qcow2 -net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

##### Error Message:

During boot, I get the following error:

```
Warning: dracut-initqueue: starting timeout scripts
[  134.151378] dracut-initqueue[307]: Warning: dracut-initqueue: timeout, still waiting for following initqueue hooks:
[  134.153530] dracut-initqueue[307]: Warning: /lib/dracut/hooks/initqueue/finished/devexists-\x2fdev\x2fsysvg\x2froon
[  134.155238] dracut-initqueue[307]:     [ -e "/dev/sysvg/root" ]
```

##### Disk Information:

I used `guestfish` to inspect the QCOW2 image and got the following output:

```
/dev/sda1: unknown
/dev/sda2: ext4
/dev/sysvg/root: xfs
```

It seems like the root filesystem `/dev/sysvg/root` does exist in the disk image, but `dracut-initqueue` is unable to find it.

##### Questions:

1. What could be causing this `dracut-initqueue` timeout?
2. How can I debug this issue further to find the root cause?
3. Are there any specific kernel configurations that I might be missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have taken the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Compiled a Custom Kernel**: I compiled a custom Linux kernel using a `.config` file from a Fedora VM. I was expecting this kernel to boot successfully since it was configured based on a working VM.
2. **Copied `initrd.img`**: I also copied the `initrd.img` from the same Fedora VM, expecting it to contain all the necessary drivers and configurations for booting.
3. **Used QEMU for Virtualization**: I used QEMU to boot the VM with the custom kernel and `initrd.img`. I specified the root filesystem as `/dev/sysvg/root` based on the disk layout.
4. **Checked Disk Layout with `guestfish`**: I used `guestfish` to inspect the QCOW2 image and confirmed that `/dev/sysvg/root` does exist and is of type `xfs`.
5. **Checked Kernel Messages**: I reviewed the kernel messages during boot but didn't find any obvious issues related to disk detection.

I was expecting the VM to boot successfully into the Fedora system with the custom kernel. However, I am encountering a `dracut-initqueue` timeout error, specifically complaining that it can't find `/dev/sysvg/root`.